# Hashing a fillable password

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have no idea how to hash fillable password input. I'm trying to hash it then gets stored to the database. Here's what I've done so far

```html
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
  public function store()
  {
      $this->validate(request(), [
          'name' => 'required',
          'email' => 'required|email',
          'password' => 'required|confirmed'
      ]);

      $pass = bcrypt(request()->password);
      $user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', $pass]));

      auth()->login($user);
    return redirect()->home();
  }
}
```

```html
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

It gives me a QueryException:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (the name i inserted, email inserted, date timestamp, date timestamp)

Comment: `['name', 'email', $pass]` looks wrong. Wouldn't that look for a request field that has the name identical to the hashed value?

Comment: what is wrong with the `RegisterController` that Laravel comes with? that **works** out of the box

Comment: `request()` will retrieve values from the original request, by passing `$pass` to it, youre are trying to retrieve a request value named `$pass`, hence you're passing `null` to `User::create` and not the password itself. Since the password field in your database does have a default value it throws a query exception. This is the issue you should solve and not the crypting itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using: `$user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', $pass]));`, you are passing an array to the `request` method and one of the elements (`$pass`) is not a key of `$request`.

I believe it should look more like:

```
$user = User::create([
  'name' => request('name'),
  'email' => request('email'),
  'password' => $pass
]);
```

**EDIT**

<strike>Also, remember that Laravel provides a Hash facade to help you with encryption:</strike>

You can also use the Hash facade to do the same as bcrypt.

*Thanks to lagbox for the correction.*

`$hashedPassword = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash:make(request('password'));`

Comment: its not encryption, its hashing btw

Comment: got it. so whenever I use User::create, it gets the value of what I've inputted from the form and I can't hard code the hash alone since there's a key pairing for $pass